# How to get this simple rails project to work on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, debugging, postgresql, heroku

I followed this [tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) to make a simple website where you can enter blog entries. I was able to get it working with a postgresql database on my computer.

Then I pushed it to heroku. It was accepted and everything seemed fine.

When I tried to go to the page in my browser though, it didn't work right. You can see it [here](https://stormy-spring-9604.herokuapp.com/).

I even tried setting up a shared postgresql database on Heroku. Am I supposed to make some changes to database.yml to get it to work?

One thing I noticed though is that what I added in the shared postgresql database, the error messages seem to indicate that it does find a database, but doesn't find the table. Am I right? I tried to manually recreate the table using the heroku console, but wasn't able to.

What's going on here? How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried  `heroku run rake db:migrate` yet?

If that doesn't fix it what does `heroku logs --tail` tell you?

Comment: Running run rake db:migrate seemed to make it work! When I ran it it said, "rake aborted! database configuration does not specify adapter" but it still worked. Do you know what that message is about?

Comment: Oh man, not sure about that error. Do you have 'pg' in your Gemfile?

Comment: I had the same error but heroku run RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate made it go away. HTH